# How to set a zmq socket timeout

Tags: c++, zeromq

I've got client and server applications using zmq in the ZMQ_REQ context. What I'm experiencing is that when the server component goes down or is unavailable, the client will wait until it is available to send its message. Is there a way to set a max wait time or timeout at the client level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess you can use the [`zmq_poll(3)`](http://api.zeromq.org/zmq_poll.html) with a timeout greater then zero.